# Actions for Timeline Apps may be sent in another language for approval?

Tags: internationalization, submit, facebook-timeline

My application default language is spanish. In a near future I want it translated by facebook, but right now I need the action verbs to be in spanish. If I send the action in spanish for approval:

a) it is approvable in spanish?

b) later can be translated with facebook translation service to other languages?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this currently is:

1. You must submit the actions in English (your site can be in any language, but just the actions).
2. You can then use the Translation app immediately upon approval as an admin of your app to create a translation of the action.

Then you can leave the other language (and English) translations to the community.

Source: Spoke to Facebook Platform Policy Team